# Previous button issue in jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I am trying to generate a previous button through `jQuery`.

My code is ...

```
$(".pagination").append("<li>" + '<a href="javascript:previous();">Prev</a>'+"</li>");

function previous(){  
    var new_page = parseInt($('#current_page').val()) - 1;
    alert(new_page);
    if(new_page!=0) {
        return new_page;
    }
}
```

Actually when i am on page 4, and press previous button i want to get the link like

```
<a href="../Log/Index?p=3">Prev</a>
```

How it is possible ?

Comment: you will have to do so manually: locatiion.href = new_page;

Answer (score 1):

Couldn't you just do something like this?

```
var prevPage = parseInt($('#current_page').val(), 10) - 1;
var linkElm = $('<a />').text('Prev').attr('href', '../Log/Index?p= ' + prevPage);
var listElm = $('<li />').html(linkElm);

$(".pagination").append(listElm);
```

That should make the a tag link correctly.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
var curr_page = parseInt($('#current_page').text());
if(curr_page > 0) {
    $(".pagination").append("<li>" + '<a  href="../Log/Index?p=' + (curr_page - 1) + '" id="prev">Prev</a>'+"</li>");
}
```

Here is the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5jnmD/